# HTTPS fails for one virtual host

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-2.4, virtualhost, https

OK, this is going to sound like a weird problem... I'm hesitant to even post it here as I can't get a good handle on how to describe it, let alone where to start looking for solutions.

I have a site (Fedora 24, standard LAMP stack, running on Amazon EC2) which recently started to respond with blank pages when requests over HTTPS were made.

So for example, if you browsed to http://example.com/coolscript.php it works just fine, however http**s**://example.com/coolscript.php returns a blank page. Web server logs show HTTP 200 for both, but with no data returned for the HTTPS version (the latter, below):

```
1.2.3.4 - - [22/Dec/2016:16:19:39 +0000] "GET /coolscript.php HTTP/1.1" 200 9069 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36"
1.2.3.4 - - [22/Dec/2016:16:19:25 +0000] "GET /coolscript.php HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36"
```

I have tried different browsers, PCs, networks, etc. all respond with a blank page.

You might be tempted (as I was) to think that I have something messed up with the virtualhost definitions in Apache, but access to simple files (even PHP scripts) work fine. The cert is valid and good to go. Other HTTPS enabled sites on the same server work fine with a different certificate, and even virtualhost aliases using the same certificate work. It's just that one hostname, over HTTPS that fails. (Kicker: the aliases that work are defined in the same virtualhost definition as the one that does not.)

I've looked at a lot of different areas hoping to find the issue, but I'm at a loss. Suggestions, comments or wild speculation welcome. :)

---

**UPDATE**

A few weeks after the original post, I encountered the same issue again, but this time HTTP was failing and HTTPS was fine. Again, just for one virtualhost (the default). A tcpdump shows no content:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 05 Jan 2017 14:33:48 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Fedora) OpenSSL/1.0.2j-fips PHP/5.6.29 mod_perl/2.0.10 Perl/v5.22.2
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.29
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: private
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Still mystified maybe even more so.

---

**8 Feb 2017 Update**

The "empty virtual host problem" came back again today for HTTP only on one virtual host. In apache's server-status the bad connections show as:

```
4-1 26987   0/2/32  R   1.55    3   223 0.0 0.02    0.13    1.2.3.4 http/1.1        
4-1 26987   0/2/22  R   1.47    4   0   0.0 0.01    0.10    1.2.3.4 http/1.1        
4-1 26987   0/1/10  R   0.07    4   2   0.0 0.00    0.19    1.2.3.4 http/1.1
```

As opposed to:

```
2-1 26210   0/22/73 W   15.51   0   0   0.0 0.06    0.38    1.2.3.4 http/1.1    vhost.com:443   GET /server-status HTTP/1.1
```

Notably, the VHost column is empty on the bad connections, so I have a new direction to focus on.

Cheers
Mike

Comment: Do you have a (modified) copy of your virtual hosts config to show?

Comment: That's a good direction to start. I'll simplify it (and see if that helps at all) and post what I end up with. It has admittedly grown over the last few years so a thorough review is not out of place.

Comment: So I was easily able to rule out most of the config by executing the following command:

>>>> mv /etc/httpd /etc/httpd.orig ; dnf reinstall httpd httpd-filesystem mod_ssl php <<<<

That pretty much made a clean apache install (including the virtualhosts config) and the issue was still present. Definitely now 100% stumped.

Comment: Also look at the output of `apachectl -S`. Its a good place to start to see if you have any actual vhost (as opposed to php) problems.

Comment: Very useful command for untangling the vhost web, thanks!

Comment: Well, I have crossed over into the bizarre. Today it happened out of the blue again, but now HTTP is returning zero data and HTTPS is working fine. I did a tcpdump and can clearly see "Content-Length: 0" in the server's response.

Comment: Here is the full response:

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 05 Jan 2017 14:33:48 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Fedora) OpenSSL/1.0.2j-fips PHP/5.6.29 mod_perl/2.0.10 Perl/v5.22.2
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.29
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: private
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: A blank page result of a PHP script is usually a PHP error with error reporting turned off. Turn on or increase error reporting, maybe with a specific logfile for that. `ini_set("log_errors", 1); ini_set("error_log", "/path/to/php_errorlog.log");`

Comment: It is time to debug your PHP application.

Comment: Error logging has been enabled, so I'll go back through the logs with a fine toothed comb to see what I can find. The bit that makes me wonder is that the *exact same* PHP scripts work fine under HTTPS. In fact, I've redirected all traffic to HTTPS and it's working great, so it seems unlikely to be related to PHP errors or load. Still puzzled and still digging...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I finally found the *real* answer: caching

I had turned on basic (level 1) caching on Simple Machines, and occasionally the cache would become corrupted and cause the site to fail, with no errors or output that I could find.

Caching is done per host, so one would fail while the others were fine. When the corrupted file in the cache expired, the problem would resolve itself.

My solution: disable SMF caching and the issue has not recurred.

Silver lining: I found and fixed a lot of server inefficiencies in pursuit of this one! :)

Answer (score 1):

`Content-Length: 0` if you have really received the header directly from Apache httpd (and not some intermediate proxy) means that Apache is at the very beginning sure there will be no more data coming from the PHP. So PHP exited as soon as the script is run. You need to `ini_set("log_errors", 1);` as Gerald suggested.

Also, establish monitoring of memory, at a minimum run `vmstat 1` and look at the colums `cache` and `free` during the problematic request, maybe the PHP script causes memory shortage.

Answer (score 1):

Likely cause: In recent versions of systemd, there is a limit to the number of "tasks" a service can spawn. For apache on Fedora 24, that was set to 512 and it was capping the server under even a light load. (A clue for me was the presence of "couldn't fork" errors from a number of sources.)

The fix is to edit "/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service" and add "TasksMax=infinity" to the Service section:

```
[Service]
TasksMax=infinity
```

So far, so good.

Comment: Although very helpful to the overall server stability, this was not the solution. The "empty virtual host problem" came back today for HTTP only on one virtual host. In apache's server-status the bad connections show as:

`4-1 26987 0/2/32 R 1.55 3 223 0.0 0.02 0.13 1.2.3.4 http/1.1  
4-1 26987 0/2/22 R 1.47 4 0 0.0 0.01 0.10 1.2.3.4 http/1.1  
4-1 26987 0/1/10 R 0.07 4 2 0.0 0.00 0.19 1.2.3.4 http/1.1 `

As opposed to:

`2-1 26210 0/22/73 W 15.51 0 0 0.0 0.06 0.38 1.2.3.4 http/1.1 vhost.com:443 GET /server-status HTTP/1.1`

Notably, the VHost column is empty on the bad connections.